# Header and Footer background images won't show in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

All right, this has been driving me crazy. In IE8, the background gradient image won't show in the header or footer, but other background images show. I have no problems in IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari or Opera. I've looked here and other places for suggested solutions, but none have worked so far. Using HTML5 and CSS3, which I know is funky in older browsers sometimes.

Here is the code for the footer:

```
footer {
text-align:center;
color:#f9f2e7;
font-size:14px; 
display:block;
background: #26b6c9;
background-image:url(images/bg-footer.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-attachment:scroll;
position:relative;
height:103px;
clear:both;
width:100%;
float:left;
}
```

And here is the header:

```
header {
background: #26b6c9;
background-image:url(images/bg-header.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-attachment:scroll;
margin: 0 auto;
position:relative;
height:159px;
width:100%;
float:left;
}
```

I have tried display:block and shorhand code like background: url(images/bg-footer.png) repeat-x top left scroll; but neither work.

The test area of the site can be found [here](http://www.bahstudios.com/bahtest/index.php). I was in the process of starting to convert this to a WordPress template when this issue was brought to my attention, so the CSS might still be a bit messy.

Comment: check out this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-make-all-browsers-render-html5-mark-up-correctly-even-ie6/

Comment: did you check whether IE8 supports HTML5's features you want?

Answer (score 3):

it's because you're using html5 - ie8 and older don't support it.

Try [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) or [html5 shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)

Answer (score 2):

IE 8 and below is not aware of the new elements like `<header>` and `<footer>`. You need to use somehting like [html5shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) in your document header.

Try adding the following to the `<head>` section:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot. That makes sense. I will try that first thing when I get back home. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because IE8 and earlier does not support the header and footer tags (html5 tags). You must create them first.